# Is there a way to display regression coefficients in a pandas data frame for categorical independent variables?

Tags: python, pandas, regression, coefficients

I have built a multiple linear regression model and I found the coefficients using `model.coef_`.
I want to make a pandas data frame which displays each of the factors and its coefficient.

`pd.DataFrame(model.coef_, x.columns, columns = ['coef']).sort_values(by = 'coef', ascending = False)` works only for the numerical independent variables. I have two columns of categorical variables and I have encoded them both.

Suppose the two values of a column are 'male' and 'female', I want to display the individual coefficients like

|  | coef |
| --- | --- |
| Male | 0.2 |
| Female | 0.3 |

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set_index after

```
(pd.DataFrame({'coef':model.coef_, 'category':x.columns})
.sort_values(by = 'coef', ascending = False)
.set_index('category'))
```

Comment: I am getting an error. 
`AttributeError: columns not found`

Comment: Is there a dataframe called x that has columns? Based on your question there seems to be one.

Comment: yes, x is the data frame consisting of the independent variables. 6 of them are numerical and 2 are categorical.

Comment: Then can you try again? There was a `]` in the comment but I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you overwrote what x is. what do you get when you call `type(x)`

Comment: `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` I think it was changed while encoding.
This is my code
`ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0,1])], remainder='passthrough')

X = ct.fit_transform(X)`

Comment: It works after converting back to a pandas frame and flattening the coefficients to a 1D numpy array. Thanks :)